# Fixing "undefined reference to" ft. makefile.txt and pthreads

Tags: c, makefile, pthreads, linker-errors

So, I'm working on a multi threaded program and I'm ready to compile, but I'm running into what I believe are linker errors.

Im sure that all of my files include my header file, and that I've externed the variables in question properly. However I still think there is an issue with the header file that I'm not seeing. It's also possible that the makefile plays a role.

Here is my makefile. I'm really new to make, and the biggest question I have here is if I included the pthread library correctly. (I use GNU on a Linux Server):

```
CFLAGS=-I. -g -pthread

ODIR=obj

DEPS = simpleServer.h
OBJ = Logger.o logQueue.o simpleServer.o SpellChecker.o Worker.o workQueue.o open_listenfd.o


%.o:: %.c %(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

server: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

And here are the errors I'm getting (I cut out the duplicates with ..):

```
cis-lclient11:~/proj3/v0.1>make -f makefile.txt
gcc -o server Logger.o logQueue.o simpleServer.o SpellChecker.o Worker.o workQueue.o open_listenfd.o -I. -g -pthread

Logger.o: In function `logger':
/proj3/v0.1/Logger.c:12: undefined reference to `logLock'.
/proj3/v0.1/Logger.c:14: undefined reference to `logCond'
.
.
/proj3/v0.1/Logger.c:20: undefined reference to `logFile'

SpellChecker.o: In function `spellCheck':
/proj3/v0.1/SpellChecker.c:14: undefined reference to `dic' 
.
.
/proj3/v0.1/SpellChecker.c:43: undefined reference to `logLock'
/proj3/v0.1/SpellChecker.c:45: undefined reference to `logCond'

Worker.o: In function `worker':
/proj3/v0.1/Worker.c:14: undefined reference to `workLock'
/proj3/v0.1/Worker.c:19: undefined reference to `workCond'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.txt:14: recipe for target 'server' failed
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

Relevant parts of header file:

```
extern FILE *dic;
extern FILE *logFile;
extern pthread_mutex_t workLock, logLock;
extern pthread_cond_t workCond, logCond;
```

Initializations (in simpleServer.c):

```
pthread_mutex_t workLock, logLock;
pthread_cond_t workCond, logCond;
FILE *logFile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
FILE *dic = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```

Sorry for the wall of code, but I've spent 3 hours making no progress, and am eager to see all of the compiler errors I've made.

Comment: No, they are _declared_ with `extern pthread_mutex_t workLock, logLock;`. You still have to find out, where they are _defined_ (the definitions seem to be missing) without the _extern_ keyword.

Comment: @Ctx I defined them all in simpleServer.c, that's what I mean by initialized in a c file.  They are defined the same way they are declared, just without the extern. Maybe it's worth mentioning that simpleServer.c uses dic, workLock, and workCond, and none of those show up as an undefined reference.

Comment: Yes, the error messages describe link errors.  They do not appear to relate to pthreads in particular.

Comment: It is unclear why you are using a double-colon rule in your makefile.  I don't think that's the issue, but double-colon rules are an obscure GNU-ism.  Do not use them until and unless you understand *exactly* what they do and why you want that.  Just change the double colon to a single one.

Comment: With that said, however, the error messages do not seem consistent with your description of your code.  We are unlikely to be able to help unless you present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your initializations include function calls:

```
pthread_mutex_t workLock, logLock;
pthread_cond_t workCond, logCond;
FILE *logFile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
FILE *dic = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```

seems to imply that this block of code is within a function.  That means that those are actually local variables to the function that contains them, *not* definitions of the variables declared `extern` in your header files.

Instead, you should define these variables in one .c file, at file scope (outside any function):

```
pthread_mutex_t workLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, logLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t workCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, logCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
FILE *logFile, *dic;
```

Then within the function you can call `fopen()`, but referencing the global variables instead of declaring new local ones:

```
logFile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
dic = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```

You will still need to use the correct link order in your Makefile - the .o file that depends on an extern object must come *before* the .o file that defines that object.